# applying preg_match on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex

If db_table with set of urls

```
1,www.something.any/djjjj
2,www.anything.any/nsmms
3,www.google.com
```

etc

and i want filter some certain url of exact prefix which is something.any
with help i've got answer say this

```
if (preg_match('/something.com/i', $url) > 0) {
    // Your error message here
}
```

**The question**

How to apply same idea of `preg_match` to delete all of it from db_table

```
$sql= "delete from urls where preg_match('/something.com/i', $url) > 0";
mysql_query($sql) or die("query failed: $sql".mysql_error());
```

it gives indeed error but that is the exact idea i want to apply so any idea !

as i'm gonna makes connection to db then call all urls in my table then apply it to delete all urls added with that exact prefix `something.com` and that is it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM urls WHERE url REGEXP 'something\.com'
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider reading this...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html.

There is a simpler method "LIKE Statement" read here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm. The second is usefull in simpler cases, where you want to select "all strings starting with *****". But it does an exact match
If any other quesions, please ask :)

Answer (score 1):

Eh ... did you know about % modidfier in strings in MySQL - eg.

```
delete from urls where url like '%something.com%'
```

it is NOT regexp, but it will work too and is much faster

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools in MySQL that are similar, 2 of which have been mentioned already

- LIKE queries
- POSIX regular expressions

If you want something more powerful you can [install the PREG plugin for MySQL](http://moxune.com/blog/2011/12/installing-the-mysql-preg-plugin-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get/).

I'd recommend trying to solve it with one of the firs 2 solutions first though as the PREG plugin can be a bit of a hassle to get running and likely won't be in your production environment unless you're in tight w/ the DBA's :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of any REGEX for MySQL (but I'm not saying there aren't, I'm just not aware of them). But for what you're describing, you could try:

```
delete from table where field like '%something.com%'
```

Comment: You're not aware of REGEX for MySQL?  Did you read @Djumaka's post before putting your answer?

Comment: We were writing our answers at the same time. Still, this has nothing to do with the fact that the solution I provided is perfectly valid.

Comment: Just saying I would probly drop a quick google for something rather than say "I'm not aware of..", looks like my vote is 'locked in now' (by SO), sorry bro.